# Removing path occurrence with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, path

I am trying to remove path occurrence in path to get a name of the folder in my variable without having to retype it.

I want to have TaskName in var called $string

I used -replace to remove part of it.

Path : C:\2017\02\21\TaskName\Step\log

This is what i already did:

```
$string = "C:\2017\02\21\TaskName\Step\log"
$string = $string -replace "\\Step\\log$"
```

I have tried something like:

```
$string  =  $string -replace "C:\\*\\*\\*\\$"
```

but it does not work

Comment: Since it seems your path starts with a date, you could do: $string.Split("\")[4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path actually exists, you can do

```
(Get-Item "C:\2017\02\21\TaskName\Step\log").Parent.Parent.Name
```

Comment: Really nice answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Split-Path` to break the last component off a path name.

Eg.

```
Split-Path 'C:\Projects\Current\TheProject`
```

returns `C:\Projects\Current`.

Using the `-leaf` parameter returns the last component instead:

```
Split-Path -leaf 'C:\Projects\Current\TheProject`
```

returns `TheProject`.

And you can chain these together

```
'C:\Projects\Current\TheSolution\ProjectOne' | Split-Path | Split-Path | Split-Path -leaf
```

to get `Current`.

Comment: It was actually useful as well. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because `$` looks for the search string from the end. Also `*` means 0 or more of preceding characters.

So your pattern `"C:\\*\\*\\*\\$"` is actually looking for *something* like `C:\\\\` at the *end of* `$string`.

In your second replace you need to pass the parameter as:

```
$string = $string -replace "^C:\\.+\\"
```

This pattern will look from the beginning (`^`), for `C:\` followed by any number of characters (`.+`) ending by `\`.

For more details execute following command in powershell

```
get-help about_regular_expressions
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation of : "C:\\*\\*\\*\\$". I will keep it in mind.